# Electron Builder Code Signing Download Certificate Error

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I'm building an Electron app and using the npm package electron-builder to build the app and installer for Windows. I'm trying to use the `CSC_LINK` and `CSC_KEY_PASSWORD` environment variables to sign the app as described here: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder#travis-appveyor-and-other-ci-servers

On first try the error and stack trace is:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: unable to verify the first certificate
at Error (native)
at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1065:38)
at emitNone (events.js:80:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:179:7)
at TLSSocket._init.ssl.onclienthello.ssl.oncertcb.TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:593:8)
at TLSWrap.ssl.onclienthello.ssl.oncertcb.ssl.onnewsession.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:425:38)
From previous event:
at Object.downloadCertificate (C:\projects\presentation\Electron\node_modules\electron-builder\src\codeSign.ts:97:18)
...
```

I then tried setting the environment variable `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` and now get a different error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Request error, status 400: Bad Request
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\projects\presentation\Electron\node_modules\electron-builder\src\httpRequest.ts:36:16)
...
```

The particular line that is being called in electron-builder's `httpRequest.ts` appears to just be using Node's https module: `https.request(...)` https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/blob/master/src/httpRequest.ts#L28

This leads me to believe there is something up with the Windows machine or certificates. I'm running this on Windows 10, node 5.9.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not certain what the root of the issue was however I was able to get everything to work by moving the file to Dropbox. I still had to set `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` and `CSC_LINK` needed to be set without quotes:

Success:
`SET CSC_LINK=https://www.dropbox.com/s/path/to/file.p12?dl=1`

Failed:
`SET CSC_LINK="https://www.dropbox.com/s/path/to/file.p12?dl=1"`

A link to the issue discussion on electron-builder GitHub can be found here: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/291

Answer (score 1):

It is better to file issue to https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues directly to get answer from the maintainers. I am active current maintainer and don't check SO, so, unlikely that you get answer quickly ;)

If issue still actual for you, file issue :)